# UPDATE and INSERT differences in syntax is an inconvenience

Tags: php

I was going through this article today.

http://vinothbabu.com/2010/05/08/update-and-insert-differences-in-syntax-is-an-inconvenience/

I was not able to understand this part of the code written by the author.

```
    list($sets,$cols,$values)=escape_arr($sets);

    $insert_sql=”INSERT INTO `avatars` “.implode(’,',$cols).” 
    VALUES(”.implode(’,',$values).”)”;

    $update_sql=”UPDATE `avatars` SET “.implode(’,',$sets).”
    WHERE userid=$userid LIMIT 1″;
```

and finally the conclusion part of the article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) turns the array of column names into a comma separated string. It does the same for the values in the INSERT statement.

$sets starts off as an associative array of column name / value pairs. This statement:

```
list($sets, $cols, $values) = escape_arr($sets);
```

reassigns the $sets variable to be a regular array containing strings like "column_name = 'value'". It does this with the helper function escape_arr in the article, which returns 3 arrays. Check the documentation for [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) if you're unsure what it does.

Then it uses the `implode` function again to build one big comma separated string of the `$sets` array. So effectively, it builds both INSERT and UPDATE statements given an associative array containing column names as keys, and their values as well... values.

Was that the question? You can insert some [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) statements in the code to follow what it's doing at every step.

Edit: sorry for the messy explanation, but I gotta run for now :)

Comment: list($sets,$cols,$values)=escape_arr($sets); -- this part may be confusing because the $sets array on the right is replaced with an array from the function escape_arr.

Comment: I was also not able to construe the conclusion on what the author is trying to explain

Comment: @theband: His conclusion is that using this pattern, it's easier to maintain your code. Or something :)

Comment: Well, simply escape_arr is a good function because you don't need to take care of all those quotes and you have a code that is more legible :-)

Comment: MartyIX can u explain me the escape_arr function and why its good to use

Answer (score 2):

On a side note, in MySQL INSERTs can use the UPDATE syntax:

```
INSERT [INTO] tbl
    SET col1 = 'value', col2 = 'value', col3 = 'value', ...
```

Refer to the [MySQL INSERT syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert.html) for the full documentation.

Answer (score 1):

That does not make any sense. He suggests to hardcode your queries because that way you can avoid thinking about them as objects (WTF?) then goes on to tell hardcoding is bad, apparently not realizing that is exactly what he is doing. Also.  `WHERE userid=$userid LIMIT 1` is bad coding practice, omitting quotes can result in SQL injection. And why the LIMIT 1? He is using non-unique userid?

There are a lot of saner solutions for separation of database layer, such as data access objects, object-relational mapping, active records...